# Wrong element height after CSS zoom

Tags: css, height, width, zooming

My `ul` element has the initial height `250px`.
Then I zoom it with CSS in JS:

```
ul.css('cssText', 'zoom:2;');
```

After this I check updated height with jQuery:

```
let newHeight = ul.height()
```

And it returns the value about 330px.
I expected that is should be 500px!
Am I wrong?

How to get the correct height?

Comment: As you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/og4m9kay/) `zoom` does not affect `height()`. So my guess is that if you `console.log(ul.height())` it will still be `330px` even if you comment out your `zoom` line. Also note [`zoom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom) is a ***non-standard*** CSS property. Which means it's not part of any web standard and support for it is not guaranteed. In short: you shouldn't use it.

Comment: You might be looking for [`transform: scale(n)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) and [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect). Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/og4m9kay/) out.